# Parsing a complex tree structured file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, s-expression

I'm tring to build up a parser reading a tree strutured file format that we are using in c# in order to modify it with a VSTO Excel interface. (Hence the C# choose otherwise I would have used Python beeing a beginer in C#...)

The format is defined as such:

```
environment type=Environment
  uservar_section type=UserVariableSection name=General
    def ExSize=2;
    var var1="something";
    var var2="2" comment="some comments";
  end uservar_section; /* General:UserVariableSection */ 
  uservar_section type=UserVariableSection name=SectionName
    def ExSize=5;
    var var1="(2*pi)";
    var var2="(pi)";
    var var3="max(var1,var2)";
    var var4="0";
    var var5="2*var3";
  end uservar_section; 
  model type=SModel name=""
      uservar_section type=UserVariableSection name=SectionName
        def ExSize=5;
        var var1="(2*pi)";
        var var2="(pi)";
        var var3="max(var1,var2)";
        var var4="0";
        var var5="2*var3";
      end uservar_section; 
  end model; 
end environment;
```

To be honest I don't know where to start in C# to read this type of file.
I've looked at OMeta but I'm not sure it is a good idea.
Would you have some general recomandation from where to start?
Does anybody here have already done such program?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you already have objects that you want to load this data in to? How is Excel related to this?

Comment: Yes I have data to load in that format. Excel is not yet related, it will just be used as user interface to replace the old fortran interface we are currently using.

Comment: A couple of options - [read the file line by line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx), parse it into some model classes and apply whatever business logic you need to get at the bits you are interested in. Or you could use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to do something similar.